How many sons did Chizkiyahu have?
As Berachot 10a-10b tells us, Chizkiyahu initially did not have children because he knew they would be wicked. It is only when the idea strikes for him to marry Yeshayahu's daughter does he comply, hoping the merit of them both will protect his children.
There is a section in Berachot 10a that the Ein Yaakov includes which is no longer a part of the Talmud. Quoting Chabad.org's translation, "Isaiah gave his daughter to Hezekiah. They gave birth to two sons: Menashe and Ravshakeh. One day, Hezekiah was carrying the boys on his shoulders… whereupon one of them said, “father’s head would be suitable for roasting a small fish, while the other boy said father’s head would be suitable for offering an idolatrous offering. When Hezekiah heard this, he cast them down to the ground. Menashe survived, while Ravshakeh died." See also Targum to Kohelet 10:9 on a different fate for Ravshakeh.
It's stated that Chizkiyahu only had two sons, but the prophet Zephaniah from Trei Asar descends from Chizkiyahu, as it says in Zephaniah 1:1, "The word of the Lord came to Zephaniah the son of Kushi, the son of Gedalya, the son of Amarya, the son of Chizkiyahu..." This Chizkiyahu is the same as King Chizkiyahu according to Ibn Ezra, Malbim, and Radak commenting on the verse. However, there are two main problems:

Why is this third son of Chizkiyahu only mentioned here and nowhere else? There is no source external from Zephaniah 1:1 that Chizkiyahu had three sons, and all other sources strongly point to him having a maximum of two children. One answer to that is that perhaps Amarya is another name for one of his two sons, but besides for there being no tradition of this, problem 2 shows it is unlikely.
From Zephaniah 1:1 we learn the rule that whenever we learn of a Tzaddik being introduced in the name of his father(s), and we never met his father(s) before, we can assume all introduced are Tzaddikim (Megillah 15a). This means that Kushi, Gedalya, and Amarya were Tzaddikim. However, there is no indicator that Chizkiyahu had any non-evil children. Quite the opposite. The dialogue between Isaiah and Chizkiyahu in Berachot 10a, "That which you are commanded, you are obligated to do; let the Holy One, then do as He sees fit," and "The decree has already been issued," seem to say this is God's will, and Chizkiyahu can't change it. While he does later recover from his illness, we see through Menashe that his wish for good children didn't come true. And if out of all of Chizkiyahu's children, Menashe was the most fitting to rule, I would hate to imagine how Amarya turned out! And yet, Megillah 15a says Amarya was a tzaddik.

As a result, I am wondering, how many sons does Chizkiyahu have? Why is Amarya only mentioned in Zephaniah 1:1 as Chizkiyahu's son and nowhere else? How does Amarya fit into all this, was he a tzaddik or a rasha?

It’s possible that the verse skips generations, as it does by Mordechai, as is evident from the Targum there.

It's also possible that Amariah was an adopted son of Chizkiyahu, or a disciple, both of which relationships are called בן in Torah terminology.

Have you considered the possibility that Amaryah simply wasn't a son of King Chizkiyahu but of a different Chizkiyah?

@Harel13 The question is according to the commentators who say that it was King Chizkiyahu.

@Meir the OP asked good questions on these commentators. It's not heresy to disagree with commentators. I recommend he consider that option.

There is a comment from Ben Yehoyada to Brachos 10a on the missing portion:

החַד אָמַר חָזִי רֵישָׁה דְאִמָא לִמטוּי בֵּיה גְלַדנָאִי.
הנה לפי סדר שמותם דנקיט הש"ס נראה שזה הראשון שאמר למטוי ביה דלדנאי היה מנשה? ונראה לי בס"ד לכך אמר דברים אלו, כי מזליה חזי שסופו לעשות תשובה ולהתתקן, ובני אדם נמשלו לדגים כנזכר בקהלת, ואמר חזי זכות אבא שיגין למטוי ביה גלדנאי הם בני אדם הרשעים, שיתבשלו ויתוקנו באש התורה, אבל רַבְשָׁקֵה אמר דבר רע ומר מאד להקריב לעבודה זרה, לכך כיון שחבטו מת תיכף על ידי נפילה זו מן השמים, כי ודאי הוא לא חבטם חביטה שיש בה שעור להמית, אלא מן השמים עשו כך לטובתו, ולכן נקרא רַבְשָׁקֵה אותיות בהשקר שהיה דבק בו, והא דארכבנהו אכתפיה, ודאי לא היה מזלזל בכבוד מלכות לפני בני אדם, אלא עשה כן בהצנע, וכונתו לשם שמים, לחבב התורה בעיני הילדים האלה בראותם שהוא מלך ומרכיבם על כתיפו בשביל ללמוד תורה.
קָרֵי אֲנַפְשֵׁיה (ישעיהו לב, ז) וְכֵלַי כֵּלָיו רָעִים. נראה לי בס"ד דהאשה נקראת כלי של בעלה, וכמו שאמרו רבותינו ז"ל אין אשה כורתת ברית אלא למי שעשאה כלי, וכן שלחה אשתו של רבי אלעזר לרבי כלי שנשתמש בו קודש ישתמש בו חול, והוא בטח שיגיע לו מצדה בזכות אביה איזה סיוע ועזר לדבר זה, ועתה בראותו כי לא הועילה גם מצידה לכך אמר וכלי, הוא שהיה כלי במצוה זו של פריה ורביה שלא נשא אשה מתחלה, הנה קרה לו שגם כליו מצד אשתו גם כן נפקי רעים ונ"ל, לכך אמר הנה לשלום מר לי מר, כי מנשה רבשקה ראשי תיבות מר, ואין שלום אלא אשה והוא קיוה כימן השלום הנשואין שנשא בת ישעיה יצא לו בנים טובים, ועתה ראה כי מן השלום יצא לו מ"ר, יען לי מר ראשי תיבות מנשה רַבְשָׁקֵה.
(he also has a possibly faulty girsa about "frying on mother's head") Behold, is it true that according the order of names the first who said to fry the fish is Menashe? And I think that it is he who said so because in the future he (Menashe) would repent and mend (his ways). People are compared to fish as mentioned in Koheles 9:12, so he said that the merit of his father was to fry fish i.e. the evil men who would be cooked and get improved in the fire of the Torah. But Ravshakeh said bad and bitter words to sacrifice to avodah zara, since he was struck immediately by the fall, it was by heavely decree, for Chizkiyahu did not hit them with deadly strike. Thus, he was called Ravshakeh, same letters as in falsity (בהשקר). (Chizkiyahu) certainly did not disdain the honor of kingship before men, but did so with modesty, and his intention was for the sake of Heaven, to endear the Torah in the eyes of these children, so that they saw that he was a king and carried them on his shoulders for learning.
Based in Yishayahu 32:7, As for the knaves (vessels), their tools are knavish, as it is said in (Sanhedrin 22b) that a woman only cuts a covenant with one who ‘makes her a vessel’... Chizkiyahu married to have children and it happened that the vesels from the side of his wife came out bad, so he said, Yishayahu 38:17 Truly, it was for my own good that I had such great bitterness ..., because Menashe and Ravshakeh initials מ"ר (bitterness). And there is no peace except a woman, and he hoped that the peace of the marriage that he had with the daughter of Isaiah would produce good sons for him, and now he saw that from peace he would produce מ"ר bitterness, the initials of Manasseh, Rabshakeh.

Ben Yehoyada seems to agree with the indication of the OP that  Chizkiyahu only had two sons due to abbreviation מ"ר. The first son Menashe, although called evil in gemarah Sanhedrin, actually repented 33 years before his death, as noted in Seder Olam Rabba 24:1.
The opinion that Chizkiya mentioned in the verse Tzephania 1:1 is king Chizkiyahu comes from ibn Ezra:

The scripture mentions the names of the fathers until it reaches the most honorable, which is King Hezekiah, and behold, according to the interpretation, Amariah was the brother of Manasseh. And do not be surprised because Josiah is third to Hezekiah, for there are more than a hundred years from the day Hezekiah grew up to father a son until Josiah became king.

Tzephaniah was a prophet during the time of Yoshiyahu, as explained in the second part of Radak. Radak actually disagrees with ibn Ezra and states

י"א כי חזקיה זה חזקיה מלך יהודה ואפשר (אבן עזרא) אלא שאין בזה ראיה אבל באמת גדולים היו אבותיו לפיכך נזכרו
There are those who say that Chizkiya is Chizkiyahu king of Yehudah and it is possible (ibn Ezra). Rather, there is no proof from these words (i.e. here in the verse). However, the ancestors of Tzephaniah were great people, that is why they were mentioned.

Therefore, we cannot accept the opinion of ibn Ezra based on Ben Yehoyada, since Ravshakeh completely became lost to the Jewish people. It would be difficult to identify Amarya with repented Menashe, since then one would have to identify Kushi with children of Menashe, etc. Alternatively, ibn Ezra might have identified Amarya with Ravshakeh, since he may not be fully consistent with Megilla 15a that the names of ancestors mentioned must all be righteous, as we find with bnei Korach. In this case, one can translate the meaning of the name Amarya not as the usual Hashem Said, but as I will embitter (אמרר) Hashem.

Thank you for your response! Thank you for clarifying the Radak's perspective. From my understanding, Radak wasn't necessarily against Ibn Ezra. I'm not so good with Hebrew, but from my understanding, he says, "it is said that this Hezekiah was Hezekiah, king of Judah, and it is possible, though there is no definitive proof. However, his ancestors were distinguished..." I understood that as him being on the fence of the subject, and is open to Ibn Ezra's interpretation.

@ThinkingJew Radak says that the other opinion is possible, but it is not his opinion. Mikraos Gedolos identifies the opinion with ibn Ezra.
